# How to keep controls visible while designing a form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi 7, controls (e.g. `TImage`) that had their `Visible` flag set to `False` would still be visible on the form designer. In recent versions of Delphi (Delphi 10.2), setting an FMX control's `Visible` flag to `False` hides the control during design time, making it harder to find on the form.

I searched through Delphi's option and the web and couldn't find a way to restore the D7 behavior, is there a solution to this?

Comment: Set the visible property in the form's constructor, always leave it `True` when designing

Comment: David, that's a work-around I'm familiar with, I was wondering if there's a setting I missed either in the UI or in the registry to change the default behavior

Comment: That is a _feature_ of the FMX designer. The VCL designer still behaves the same as before.

Comment: I'm aware it's a feature, it's just an annoying one (to me).  When I'm designing the form, I want to quickly access the components on the form, which is hard to do if they are invisible.

Comment: @bLight that is what the [Structure Pane](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structure_View) is good for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the structure pane **and** a sensible naming convention far away from Label1 or Button23 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in FMX. Use structure view to find your component.